# SonarQube Scanner: I know there are errors in the javascript, but the scan doesn't seem to catch them

Tags: jenkins

I am having trouble running SonarQube Scanner.  Everything seems to be configured correctly according to the build log.  However, when I click on the link to view my report, the report show 0 technical debt and 0 issues.  I know there are errors in the javascript, but the scan doesn't seem to catch them.  I think I may be missing something in the configuration, but according to the log, everything went well.

I am attaching the log and a jpeg of the report page.
[report jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0vlC.jpg)

> [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) @ myproject ---
>
> [INFO] User cache: /home/ltbldmgt/.sonar/cache
>
> [INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5.5
>
> [INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
>
> [INFO] [14:03:15.487] Load global referentials...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:16.286] Load global referentials done: 802 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:16.304] User cache: /home/ltbldmgt/.sonar/cache
>
> [INFO] [14:03:16.316] Install plugins
>
> [INFO] [14:03:16.490] Install JDBC driver
>
> [INFO] [14:03:16.511] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://lt00nxam00f5000.opr.mysite.org/sonar
>
> [INFO] [14:03:18.358] Initializing Hibernate
>
> [INFO] [14:03:20.687] Load project referentials...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:21.343] Load project referentials done: 656 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:21.343] Load project settings
>
> [INFO] [14:03:21.807] Loading technical debt model...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:21.831] Loading technical debt model done: 24 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:21.835] Apply project exclusions
>
> [INFO] [14:03:22.184] -------------  Scan myproject
>
> [INFO] [14:03:22.188] Load module settings
>
> [INFO] [14:03:22.678] Language is forced to js
>
> [INFO] [14:03:22.680] Loading rules...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:23.696] Loading rules done: 1016 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:23.733] Configure Maven plugins
>
> [INFO] [14:03:23.923] Compare to previous analysis (2016-09-01)
>
> [INFO] [14:03:23.940] Compare over 30 days (2016-08-02, analysis of 2016-08-01 13:50:56.779)
>
> [INFO] [14:03:23.942] No quality gate is configured.
>
> [WARN] [14:03:25.039] Accessing the filesystem before the Sensor phase is deprecated and will not be supported in the future. Please update your plugin.
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.039] Index files
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.150] 0 files indexed
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.156] Base dir: /opt/ltsapps/jenkins/workspace/myproject
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.156] Working dir: /opt/ltsapps/jenkins/workspace/myproject/src
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.156] Source paths: pom.xml
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.157] Binary dirs: target/classes
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.157] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.157] Index files
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.212] 0 files indexed
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.213] Quality profile for js: Sonar way
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.244] Sensor QProfileSensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.268] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 24 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.268] Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.268] Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.268] Found SCM type: svn
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.270] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.271] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8 done: 1 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.271] Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 3 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.271] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.282] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 11 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.282] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.294] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 12 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.294] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.339] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 45 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.339] Sensor FileHashSensor...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.340] Sensor FileHashSensor done: 1 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.340] Sensor Maven dependencies...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.409] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 69 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.411] Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped)...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.412] DefaultCpdEngine is used for js
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.412] Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped) done: 1 ms
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.890] Execute decorators...
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.944] Saving metrics for: myproject project.
>
> [INFO] [14:03:25.974] Metrics saved successfully.
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.260] Store results in database
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.372] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://lt00nxam00f5000.opr.mysite.org/sonar/dashboard/index/myproject
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.759] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.760] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.780] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.803] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2016-08-04 and 2016-08-31
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.809] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2015-09-03 and 2016-08-04
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.816] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2011-09-08 and 2015-09-03
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.825] -> Delete data prior to: 2011-09-08
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.833] -> Clean myproject [id=7000]
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.839] <- Clean snapshot 81696
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.889] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
>
> [INFO] [14:03:26.900] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 14.798 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-01T14:03:26-05:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 32M/1238M
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Sonar analysis completed: SUCCESS

Any ideas as to what I may be missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: If I were you I would first solve warning. Sometimes it hides real problems. Could you update your plugin and try again ,

Comment: Thanks, I will try that again, but the warning doesn't pose any problems with other sonarqube scans.  The difference is that this one uses the javascript plugin.